# Configure Data source error in JBOSS eAP 6 with oracle

Tags: oracle, jboss, datasource

Ia m using jboss 6eap .when i try to configure datasource for oracle DB i getting the below exception

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleDriver (missing)
dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS,
             service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS]
```

*config:*

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Here is my standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
  <datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
              pool-name="ExampleDS" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>sa</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
  <datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS" jta="true"
              pool-name="DefaultDS_pool" use-ccm="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.236.190.54:1521</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
    <pool>
      <prefill>false</prefill>
      <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
      <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
      <user-name>*</user-name>
      <password>*</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
  <drivers>
    <driver module="com.h2database.h2" name="h2">
      <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
    <driver module="com.oracle.ojdbc6" name="ojdbc6">
      <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
      <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
  </drivers>
</datasources>
```

I tried out even stackoverflow .it seems to be everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following things need to be checked on your side.

Copy your downloaded jar to following defined location or create a dir structure if not present.

```
JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main
```

You can find a very good tutorial here : [How to](https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/)